# getResources().getColor() is deprecated

Tags: java, android

Почему выводит ошибку getResources().getColor() is deprecated при попытке изменить цвет фона?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это не ошибка, но предупреждение об устаревании метода. Т.е. он будет работать, но, однажды, может перестать. Теперь надо пользоваться методом `ContextCompat#getColor(Context context, int color)` вот [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31590927/3212712):

```
ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.your_color);
```

Если заглянуть в [исходники](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.java) сего метода, то можно увидеть как он работает:

```
public static final int getColor(Context context, int id) {
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {
        return ContextCompatApi23.getColor(context, id);
    } else {
        return context.getResources().getColor(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ага, понял. А что такое ContextCompat?

Comment: И можно ли писать "по-новому" на андроид 5.0.2?

Comment: @ikerya, `ContextCompat` это вспомогательный класс из библиотеки поддержки для обеспечения обратной совместимости. Как видно из ответа - позволяет получить цвет на всех версиях ОС в одну строку вместо 4-х. Использовать его можно на всех версиях ОС.

Comment: Хорошо, а `context` что это?

Comment: И нужно ли его определять? Он просто у меня красным свеиится

Comment: @ikerya, контекст это класс, представляющий собой текущий процесс приложения (примерно, это сложно определяемое понятие). Каждая активити его наследует, засим, если код в активити пишется, то контекст это - `this`

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь!